# CSS 100% height with a sidebar

Tags: css, height

i'm having a problem with 100% height for CSS. I've searched for numerous tutorial as well as solutions but i can't seem to get the results i want. What i have is a sidebar and a main column where the content will be placed.

As the main column stretches due to the content i want the background of the sidebar to stretch as well. But what i get is that the sidebar's background kept getting stuck at a point and it does not goes all the way down.

[image]

The black background is my side bar and the content seem to keep overflow to the side.

My codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

<title>CSS 100% Height</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="sidecolumn">
</div>
<div id="maincolumn">
    <div id="content">
    contents
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    background: #EEE;
    font: 1.5em arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sidecolumn {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    }

#maincolumn {
    height: 100%;
    }

#page {
    height: 100%;
    }
```

the tut i saw and tried
http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve your desired through `display:table-cell` property.

Firstly define `display:table` to your parent div, then define `display:table-cell` to your child div's, then both div will come equal vertically.

**updated css**

```
#content {
    background: #EEE;
    font: 1.5em arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    display: table-cell;
}

#sidecolumn {
    width: 500px;
    background: #000;
    display:table-cell;
}

#maincolumn {
    height: 100%;
}

#page {
    height: 100%;
    display:table;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9dhbL8ke/

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning to position the sidebar and the mainbar . . .

```
 #sidecolumn {
position:relative;
top: 0px;
left:0px;
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
background: #000;
float: left;
}


#maincolumn {
position: relative;
left: 101px;
height: 100%;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVtc9/)

Answer (score -1):

use equal height function

jQuery

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    equalHeight($(".eheight));

});
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="sidecolumn eheight">
</div>
<div id="maincolumn eheight">
    <div id="content">
    contents
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```